# Help with finding current in ab line

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I tried to solve the system of linear equations using Kirchhoff''s circuit laws. But I always got two equations that are not independent. And got 7 variables and 6 equations. I can't understand how to find current in AB line. Help please

Comment: Show us Your calculations. No one here make Your homework for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing is not very clear. If by A and B you mean those points at the extremes of your circuits extending out like two terminal to the outside world, then you can't.

You can't because the current through your two-terminal network cannot be determined without knowing the voltage across those two terminals, if they are connected to the outside world.

You can determine a Thévenin or Norton equivalent circuit of your network, though. Once you determine such an equivalent circuit, you can determine easily the current through the network *once you connect a load across its terminals*.

On the other hand, if the circuit is not intended to be connected to an external load, i.e. the circuit is just what you have drawn, the current through AB is zero, since Jkz (or whatever current is meant - I cannot decode your handwriting) leaving the circuit at A must be zero (it is an open branch).

**EDIT** (after the OP clarified his question and updated the circuit)

You can simplify the circuit connected to the short circuit with various techniques. One involves the delta-wye transformation formulas, but they are a bit unwieldy and you may not know them.

Another way is to use what is sometimes known as the "generator splitting technique". You can "split" the generator by substituting it with two identical generators in parallel (i.e. add another identical generator in parallel with your generator).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDG5xq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then notice that there is no current flow across the connection between the two generators at node 1, so you can "split" that connection, so that you end up with two generators, both connected on one side to node 3. The other side of one the generators is connected ("after the split") in series with R2. the other generator is connected in series with R3 and R5.

From then you can go on using repeated application of thevenin/norton theorem, since you end up with generators in series or in parallel with resistors.

Comment: Line between a and b points is short circuit, so there is no elements on it. Simply straight line

Comment: @ArtyomGabidullin So \$R_4\$ is shorted, then?

Comment: @ArtyomGabidullin I don't see any short circuit in your drawing. Please, post the relevant drawing of the situation you want to analyze.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. [Here](https://pp.vk.me/c604630/v604630037/f34f/pA5KgIJi6MQ.jpg) scheme with added short circuit

Comment: I'm trying to count the parameters of equivalent generator, and now I'm trying to count short circuit current

Comment: @ArtyomGabidullin Please, don't post information relevant to your question in a comment, edit your question inserting the correct information instead.

Comment: @ArtyomGabidullin Moreover, what do you mean by "count", do you mean "calculate", "compute"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sry for my English

Comment: @ArtyomGabidullin. Ok. Another question, since you use symbols in a way I've never seen: that generator marked E in the circuit is a voltage or a current source? The symbol is that of a current source, but E is used sometimes to mark voltage sources.

Comment: That's voltage source.